# How to specify the type for a callback function?

Tags: typescript

How do I do the equivalent of the following Javascript in TypeScript:

```
function f1(callback) {
   // do some work
   if (err)
     callback(err);
   else
     callback(undefined);
}
```

`callback` is a function and I don't want to specify it to be of type `any`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you would indicate the type for any lambda function:

```
function f1(callback: (err: SomeErrorType) => ReturnType) {
   // do some work
   if (err)
     callback(err);
   else
     callback(undefined);
}
```

Or if `callback` doesn't return anything:

```
function f1(callback: (err: SomeErrorType) => void) {
   // do some work
   if (err)
     callback(err);
   else
     callback(undefined);
}
```

You can also define the type externally, which would allow you to reuse it in multiple places:

```
type Callback = (err: SomeErrorType) => void

function f1(callback: Callback) {
   // do some work
   if (err)
     callback(err);
   else
     callback(undefined);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a function signature to specify the argument and return type of the callback. Assuming a single optional string argument and a void return type this is what it would look like

```
function f1(callback: (err?: string) => void) {
    // do some work
    let err = '';
    if (err)
        callback(err);
    else
        callback();
}
```